# Using Gmail for several e-mail accounts with IMAP

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I'm using Gmail to read mail from a couple of other accounts that I've got, I've just added the accounts in the Gmail settings under 'Accounts and import'. But I haven't found the ability to add IMAP accounts, only POP3. Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5):

Gmail cannot read mail from external IMAP accounts.

Instead, you can set the external account to forward to Gmail, or just use POP.
If the external account supports IMAP, but not POP or forwarding, you're out of luck.
I'm not aware of any such email providers.

Comment: https://fastmail.fm 's Guest user has just such a restriction - IMAP access allowed, no POP3 or SMTP.

Comment: I tried to click the hollow check when I saw your answer but I couldn't, I got a message I had to wait ten minutes or so. Now I can't see the hollow check anymore.

Comment: The Gmail App on Android, however, can read emails from several external IMAP accounts and keeps the IMAP accounts separately. Just click on "Add Account" in the settings.